# as.Date error when converting using tryFormats

Tags: r, rstudio, as.date

I'm running this command in RStudio:

```
as.Date("31.01.07", tryFormats = c("%d.%m.%y"))
```

and I get this error:

Error in charToDate(x) :
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

When I try this:

```
as.Date("31.01.07", format = "%d.%m.%y")
```

it works and give me this:

[1] "2007-01-31"

I'm using RStududio Version 1.2.5042 with R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) -- "Wooden Christmas-Tree"

Should I reinstall R or trash my computer?

Comment: Can you update your R version.  the `tryFormats` may be applicable in the new version.  it is working fine with `R 4.0.4` `as.Date("31.01.07", tryFormats = c("%d.%m.%y"))#
[1] "2007-01-31"`

Comment: *"... or trash my computer"*? An extreme option (I know it's mostly in jest). One might exercise caution when following howtos and tutorials for "current" R (r-release) while using a version that was updated 5 years ago (3.2.4, Mar 3016) and stopped being tested almost 4 years ago (3.4.0, Apr 2017, when "r-oldrel" should have shifted to 3.3.3 ... if I'm reading the list of R versions correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The addition of `tryFormats` happened in `R 3.5.0` as showed in [NEWS](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/NEWS.3).  From the OP's post, the `R version` is `3.2.3`.  So, it is showing an error

> The character methods for as.Date() and as.POSIXlt() are more
> flexible *via* new arguments tryFormats and optional: see their
> help pages.

---

In `R 4.0.4` on a Mac, the code gives

```
as.Date("31.01.07", tryFormats = c("%d.%m.%y"))
#[1] "2007-01-31"
```